# How to render objects and side panel using opengl?

Tags: opengl

Suppose you have some objects which are rendered based on camera position and then you have side pannels (some buttons, text, etc.) which are always at the same position on the screen.

How could I achieve this effect with opengl?

I'm not sure what I should be looking for but I have two ideas how this could be done. The first is to draw semi-transparent texture after applying view and projection matrix. The second is to render to texture like [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) and then draw it on a plane and render also the pannels.

What method is the most efficient and/or what method is usually used by game developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glViewport(full_window);
set_projection_and_modelview_for_scene();
draw_scene();

glViewport(sidebar_position);
glScissor(sidebar_position);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
set_projection_and_modelview_for_sidebar();
draw_sidebar();
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```